# How to prevent player from flying when picking up objects underneath him?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For picking-up objects, I chose to make the picked-up object float in the middle of the screen in front of the camera following a certain point.

```
 raycastPos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(raycastPos, mainCamera.transform.forward, out hit, maxDistance, 1 << interactableLayerIndex))
        {
            lookObject = hit.collider.transform.gameObject;
            reticle.color = new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.75f);

        }
        else
        {
            lookObject = null;
            reticle.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.75f);
        }
        if (PickingUp)
        {
            if (currentlyPickedUpObject == null)
            {
                if (lookObject != null)
                {
                    if (hit.distance >= minDistance)
                    {
                        PickUpObject();
                    } 
                 }
             }
        }
 public void PickUpObject()
    {
        physicsObject = lookObject.GetComponentInChildren<PhysicsObjects>();

        currentlyPickedUpObject = lookObject;

        // currPicked = true;  

        pickupRB = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;

        physicsObject.playerInteractions = this;
    }
```

I'm facing an issue with this, Whenever the player is standing over a pickable object and picks it up (while standing on it), the player flies on top of the object like this:

[image]]

Here is another image from the Scene window :
[image]
You can see clearly here what's happening when the player picks up an object underneath him.
How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Please add a more descriptive image/video.

Comment: image is not clear?

Comment: will try to add a video

Comment: Can't make sense of player in image.

Comment: ok I added another image. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the picked up object in a new layer. Then disable any physics interaction between player and said layer. You will then observe that the picked up object and the player may intersect. To fix this, you can project the object outside of your player collider using a few more ray casts. Given that the object's collider is convex, calculations should be fairly simple.

Comment: The player and the picked-up object don't have the same layer.  what do you mean by diable physics interaction between player and picked up object layer?

Comment: In the Physics settings, you can disable physical interactions between layers: `Project Settings` > `Physics` > `Layer Collision Matrix`.